# tvOS AppleTV 4. Can't change colors

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm running a simple tvOS/TVML Client Server app. Everything was working well until it came to styling.
For some reason changing the color of some text elements or the background-color of layout elements causes the not to render.

For example in my TVML template:

this renders

```
<header>
    <title>Test</title>
</header>
```

this doesn't

```
<header>
    <title style="color: rgb(255,255,255);">Test</title>
</header>
```

Anyone know why this would be?

I can see in the Safari inspector that the elements are in the DOM, they just don't show up. I've tried this in the simulator and on the device.

For reference I'm running Xcode Version 7.3.1

Comment: Interestingly if I set the theme attribute on the template to 'dark' the text now renders in the correct colour.

Comment: You're right, this worked for me too, specifically with a "loadingTemplate".

Answer (score 0):

The title is there but you are not able to see it because the lighter a color is the more transparent it is. This only seems to be a bug(feature?) for titles in headers on certain templates.